# Bootstrap 3 fixed size template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create fixed szie page, **without common scrollbar**. Scrollbars have only two div's, where content content goes beyond of div (contend data and sidebar listing area) as on picture. I alreay did it without bs3, and use javascript (for calculate new offsets on page resize).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/37E2j.jpg

Today I tried to create fixed size template with Bootrstrap3, but i can't do it. It's possible to do using bs3? Anybody can show how it is done?

I tried modify this code http://www.bootply.com/0FG70wcT3B. I do left and right headers.

Comment: It is possible. BS is the same HTML and CSS as your own code but with some prebuild blocks. What is the problem here? It's difficult to help when there's nothing to work with. Make a fiddle or something with your code.

Comment: There is no way with BS out-of-the-box, but you can do something like this: http://codeply.com/go/KRplw7mral

Comment: @mMoovs I'm sorry, but I do not know where to begin to offer the code example. I do not have a any working version. May be someone suggest sample.

Comment: @Skelly this example don't work correct if page resized to small size.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to modify it. That's why I said "something like this".

Comment: @Skelly I've seen this example, if I knew how to modify the code to the desired state, I would not have asked the question here.

Comment: You asked if it was possible. The answer is "yes".

Comment: @Skelly, okay, but I wrote that I did not get to do it. Maybe someone can do it to help me.

Comment: In your question you indicate that you've already tried to do this. Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: @BSMP I added link into the question